Sublime Text :: Sort Lines By Regex Matches
Title is pretty much self explanatory.
I have made a sorted list (by countries) of all of the places I have been in :
 Albania :: Tirana

 Austria :: Vienna

 Belarus :: Minsk

 Belgium :: Brussels

 Bulgaria :: Burgas
 Bulgaria :: Sofia
 Bulgaria :: Varna

 Cambodia :: Phnom Penh
 Cambodia :: Siem Reap

 China :: Beijing

 Croatia :: Zagreb

 Cyprus :: Ayia Napa
 Cyprus :: Larnaca

 Czechia :: Prague

 Denmark :: Copenhagen

 Estonia :: Tallinn

 France :: Metz
 France :: Paris

 Germany :: Berlin
 Germany :: Munich

 Greece :: Rohdus

 Hungary :: Budapest

 India :: Anjuna Beach
 India :: Baga Beach
 India :: Calangute Beach
 India :: Fort Kochi*
 India :: Mumbai
 India :: Mysore
 India :: Sivananda Ashram
 India :: Thiruvananthapuram
 India :: Varkala

 Ireland :: Dublin

 Israel :: Ashdod
 Israel :: Dimona
 Israel :: Eilat
 Israel :: Givatayim
 Israel :: Hadera
 Israel :: Haifa
 Israel :: Holon
 Israel :: Jerusalem
 Israel :: Lod
 Israel :: Modi'in-maccabim-re'ut
 Israel :: Nes ẔIyyona
 Israel :: Netanya
 Israel :: Or Yehuda
 Israel :: Petaẖ Tiqwa
 Israel :: Qiryat Bialik
 Israel :: Ramat Hasharon
 Israel :: Ramla
 Israel :: Ra‘ananna
 Israel :: Rehovot
 Israel :: Rishon Leẕiyyon
 Israel :: Rosh Ha‘ayin
 Israel :: Tel Aviv-yafo
 Israel :: Tiberias
 Israel :: Yehud-monosson

 Italy :: Milan
 Italy :: Rome

 Kosovo :: Pristina

 Laos :: Luang Prabang
 Laos :: Vang Vieng
 Laos :: Vientiane

 Latvia :: Riga

 Lithuania :: Vilnius

 Luxembourg ::

 Montenegro :: Bar
 Montenegro :: Budva
 Montenegro :: Kotor
 Montenegro :: Perast
 Montenegro :: Tivat
 Montenegro :: Ulcinj

 Netherlands :: Amsterdam
 Netherlands :: Rotterdam

 North Macedonia :: Ohrid
 North Macedonia :: Skopje

 Norway :: Oslo

 Philippines :: Manila

 Poland :: Auschwitz
 Poland :: Kraków
 Poland :: Przemysl
 Poland :: Warsaw

 Portugal :: Lisbon
 Portugal :: Porto

 Romania :: Bucharest

 Russia :: Moscow
 Russia :: Saint Petersburg

 Serbia :: Belgrade
 Serbia :: Niš

 Singapore :: Bayfront
 Singapore :: Bugis
 Singapore :: Changi
 Singapore :: Chinatown
 Singapore :: City Hall
 Singapore :: Clarke Quay
 Singapore :: Dhoby Ghaut
 Singapore :: Little India
 Singapore :: Marina Bay
 Singapore :: Orchard
 Singapore :: Raffles Place
 Singapore :: Somerset

 Slovakia :: Bratislava

 South Korea :: Seoul

 Spain :: Barcelona

 Sweden :: Stockholm

 Switzerland :: Basel
 Switzerland :: Zürich

 Thailand :: Bangkok
 Thailand :: Chiang Mai
 Thailand :: Chiang Rai
 Thailand :: Hat Yai
 Thailand :: Ko Pha Ngan
 Thailand :: Krabi
 Thailand :: Nong Khai
 Thailand :: Pai
 Thailand :: Pattaya
 Thailand :: Phuket
 Thailand :: Udon Thani

 Turkey :: Antalya
 Turkey :: Bodrum
 Turkey :: Istanbul

 Ukraine :: Kherson
 Ukraine :: Kyiv
 Ukraine :: Lviv
 Ukraine :: Mykolaiv
 Ukraine :: Odesa
 Ukraine :: Uman

 United Kingdom :: London
 United Kingdom :: Manchester

 Vietnam :: Da Nang
 Vietnam :: Hanoi
 Vietnam :: Ho Chi Minh City
 Vietnam :: Mui Ne
 Vietnam :: Nha Trang

I want to be able to sort it by cities or in other words by the last regex match in that specific case.
I can easily grab them all by regex search:
:: (.*?)\n

But now I need the final step which is sort those selected matches

Do you want to sort just by cities, or "by country, then by city within each country"?

In either case, I'd highly suggest to stop trying to do something moderately complex with an editor and use simple CLI instead - e.g. sort -t ':' -k3,3 cities.txt will sort by city ignoring the country, unless you have bare semicolons somewhere. You can | grep -vE '^$' to remove blank lines from output. sort -t':' -k1,1 -k3,3 will sort "country, then city within each".
